# Is Lich Bane still a viable item for Fizz

Tags: league-of-legends

The question is pretty straightforward. Is Lich Bane still a viable item for Fizz. It's 99% of the times the first item I buy and I keep it until the end. It is a good item to start your build with and it still remains a good item on late game or should I sell it and buy something else?

Comment: Yes, absoloutely

Comment: Thanks for the reassurance, even though the reasons still have me worried

Comment: http://www.probuilds.net/champions/Fizz - Every single one has a lichbane

Comment: Yeah but doesn't it scales off late game? Maybe it's more worth it to buy DFG?

Comment: I dont see why you wouldnt get both.
Deathcap, Boots, Lichbane, DFG, Zhonyas, Void Staff

Comment: I always take GA on Fizz. He's becoming extremely annoying and it just takes too much time to kill him in a TF considering that I'll have E, Zhonyans, E, GA, E. Just too much time to kill 1 champion. No need to talk about my Q and flash.. So GA is a must item for me on especially on Fizz. So no space for DFG at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't say it's a good item... **It's crucial**.

Lichbane has basically everything that fizz needs: AP, Mana, Movementspeed and the Best Passive an Item could ever have for fizz: On-Hit Bonus Magic damage w that scales with AP and that gets applied instantly with your Q.

There is no Item for fizz that comes even close to this one. You should rush a Sheen almost all the time as a core Item on him. Sometimes even before boots of speed. The Active and Passive stats are just too good and they can help you snowball early.

Comment: That's the explanation I was looking for.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the sheen MIGHT get procced by Fizz's Q. I believe that the tooltip states that literally.

Comment: @ValentinGrégoire [It does get applied intstantly if it's off-cooldown](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Fizz)

Comment: So I don't have to auto attack the enemy after I Q+W him?

Comment: @zETO no you don't have to. But you could use W 1.5 seconds after you hit him with Q in early levels to get an additional sheen proc (although it's very situational).